# Not allow Korean character(Hangul) for input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internationalization

I want to allow typing Latin Characters but I don't want user can type Korean Hangul characters.
Please help me answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to restrict the text to Latin Characters only?

Comment: This is the table of Unicode ranges of the basic multilingual plane: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane . If you want to restrict only Korean (and not Chinese, Japanese, Indonesian, etc.), you need to match any character in the Hangul ranges (there are 5 of them).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this article, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_language_and_computers

You would want to do something like this (untested):

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function (e) {
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;

    // Hangul Syllables
    if (key >= 0xAC00 && key <= 0xD7A3) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Hangul Jamo
    if (key >= 0x1100 && key <= 0x11FF) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Hangul Compatibility Jamo 
    if (key >= 0x3130 && key <= 0x318F) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Hangul Jamo Extended-A
    if (key >= 0xA960 && key <= 0xA97F) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Hangul Jamo Extended-B 
    if (key >= 0xD7B0 && key <= 0xD7FF) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

However, this would not stop anyone from copying/pasting Hangul characters into the input field, you would need to find something separate for that.

A more simplified way is to use form validation (this is a more simplified approach):

```
<input type="text" pattern="[^가-힣]+">
```

What you should do is instead be testing for the characters on the server side and returning a form error.

Comment: $("#TLPHN").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {
  var val = $(this).val();
    if(/[\u3131-\uD79D]/gi.test(val)){ //  /[^\u0000-\u007F]/gi : unicode chars, /[\u3131-\uD79D]/gi : kor chars
     $(this).val(val.replace(/[\u3131-\uD79D]/gi, ""));
    }
 });